# I am attempting to use functions to create a GUI using class to validate inputs however the inputs are not being passed through the class?

Tags: python, function, class, tkinter

```
    def Begining_menu():
    
        global main_screen
        main_screen = Tk()
        main_screen.geometry("400x450")
        main_screen.title("SDRMS")
    
        Label(text="Select an option".upper()).grid(row=0, column=0)
        Button(text="Admin", height="2", width="30", fg="green", command="login_Admin").grid(row=4, column=0)
        Button(text="Headmaster", height="2", width="30", fg="green", command="login_Headmaster").grid(row=5, column=0)
        Button(text="Finance department", height="2", width="30", fg="green", command="login_Finance_department").grid(row=6, column=0)
        Button(text="Maths department", height="2", width="30", fg="green", command=login_head_maths).grid(row=7, column=0)
        Button(text="Geography department", height="2", width="30", fg="green", command="login_head_geography").grid(row=8, column=0)
        Button(text="History department", height="2", width="30", fg="green", command="login_head_history").grid(row=9, column=0)
        main_screen.mainloop()
```

'login GUI for the head of maths'
def login_head_maths():
department_name = DEPARTMENT_NAMES[1]

```
        global login_screen
        login_screen = Toplevel(main_screen)
        login_screen.title("Login")
        login_screen.geometry("300x250")
        Label(login_screen, text="Please enter details below to login").grid(row=0, column=0)
        Label(login_screen, text="").grid(row=1, column=0)
    
        username_verify = StringVar()
        password_verify = StringVar()
    
        global username_login_entry
        global password_login_entry
    
        Label(login_screen, text="Username * ").grid(row=2, column=0)
        username_login_entry = Entry(login_screen, textvariable=username_verify)
        username_login_entry.grid(row=3, column=0)
        Label(login_screen, text="").grid(row=4, column=0)
        Label(login_screen, text="Password * ").grid(row=5, column=0)
        password_login_entry = Entry(login_screen, textvariable=password_verify)
        password_login_entry.grid(row=6, column=0)
        Label(login_screen, text="").grid(row=7, column=0)
    
        first = validate_login_entries(username_verify.get(), password_verify.get(), department_name)
    
        Button(login_screen, text="Login", width=10, height=1,
               command=first.check_identity_exsists).grid(row=8, column=0)
```

'Validation class'
class validate_login_entries:
def **init**(self, username, password, department_name):
self.username = username
self.password = password
self.department_name = department_name

```
        def check_inputs(self):
            print(self.username, self.password, self.department_name)
            if len(self.username) > 5 and len(self.username) < 10 and len(self.password) > 3 and len(self.department_name) > 4:
                return True
            else:
                return False
    
        def check_identity_exsists(self):
            hashed_password = hashlib.sha256(str.encode(self.password)).hexdigest()
            check = self.check_inputs()
            if check:
                items.execute("SELECT * FROM logins WHERE Name_department=:name_department AND Username=:username AND Password_hash=:password_hashed",
                              {"name_department": self.department_name, "username": self.username, "password_hashed": hashed_password})
                identity = items.fetchone()
                Database.commit()
    
                if identity is None:
                    print(identity)
    
                else:
                    Main_code.login_head_maths()
            else:
                print("This is not working")
    
    
    print(Begining_menu())
```

Comment: Please clarify what exactly the issue is, and provide a [mcve].

Comment: There doesn't even appear to be a class in your code (though it is too much code for a minimal example and parts are out of code blocks).  If you are doing object oriented programming, using `global` variables is highly discouraged.

Comment: When the user inputs their username and password and clicks the button for some reason the the inputs are not being recorded and are resulting in the inputs not being present.

Comment: I'am new to coding and am still building an understanding

Comment: class validate_login_entries:
    def __init__(self, username, password, department_name):
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
        self.department_name = department_name

Comment: In `login_head_maths` the statement `first = validate_login_entries ...` is executed before the user has a chance to input anything.  The parameters will be empty strings.

Comment: How do I correct this ?

Answer (score 0):

I've simplified to show the issue.  `validate_login_entries` must be called after the user has entered Username and a Password.  It needs to be called when the button is clicked.  In the question it's called as the GUI is being defined.  Given that, the definition of the class may need to change but I've left it as it was for the answer.

```
import tkinter as tk

class validate_login_entries: 
    def __init__(self, username, password, department_name): 
        self.username = username 
        self.password = password 
        self.department_name = department_name

    def check_inputs(self):
        print(self.username, self.password, self.department_name)
        return ( len(self.username) > 5 and len(self.username) < 10 
          and len(self.password) > 3 and len(self.department_name) > 4 )
    
    def check_identity_exsists(self):
        check = self.check_inputs()
        if check:
            print( 'Entries meet spec.')
        else:
            print( 'Entries fail spec.')
    
root = tk.Tk()

user = tk.StringVar()
pword = tk.StringVar()

tk.Label( root, text = 'User Name').grid( row = 0, column = 0 )
tk.Entry( root, width = 12, textvariable = user ).grid( row = 0, column = 1 )

tk.Label( root, text = 'Password').grid( row = 1, column = 0 )
e1 = tk.Entry( root, width = 12, textvariable = pword, show = '*' ).grid( row = 1, column = 1 )
# show = '*' to hide the password as it's typed

def on_click():
    valid = validate_login_entries( user.get(), pword.get(), 'Maths' )
    # This must run after ussr has input text
    valid.check_identity_exsists()

tk.Button( text = 'Login', command = on_click ).grid()

tk.mainloop()
```

An alternative could be to pass the two StringVars to the class.  Then the current state of these vars could be used in the processing within the class.